# Scroll to item in lazycolumn with sticky header

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have an issue with `stickyHeader` inside `LazyColumn`.
Indeed, the content pass "under" the `stickyHeader` when scroll.
An option is to set a background to this `stickyHeader` but with this solution, I'm facing another issue which is:

- When I scroll to an item below the `stickyHeader` (programmatically), this item is truncated because its under the `stickyHeader`.
  I can't pass a correct `offset` to the `scrollToItem` statement because when screen are small, the `stickyHeader` isn't compute and I don't know its height (header is larger than screen).

Is there any way to `scrollToItem` and say "at the end of the scroll, the item should be at the bottom of the sticky header" instead of at the top of sticky header?

Thanks!